# Send to webview using button on click

Tags: android

In android I want to use multiple button on same on-create method. 1st will pass to another activity and 2nd to a webview.1st one is working fine But when I click the 2nd button the application stop working.

```
SelectService.java

package qcash.bd.qcashwallet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelectService extends Activity {

    Button btnrecharge;
    Button btnFundTransfer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_service);

        Button btnrecharge = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecharge);
        Button btnFundTransfer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFundTransfer);

        btnrecharge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SelectOperator.class);
                startActivity(intentMain);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recharge",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        btnFundTransfer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SelectService.this, WebViewPtoP.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
     return true;
     }
}
```

WebViewPtoP.java

```
package qcash.bd.qcashwallet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class WebViewPtoP extends Activity {


     private WebView mWebView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_ptop);

    // *********************Webview****************************
      mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewPtoP);
      mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://27.147.128.98/bl_apps/welcome/P2P_Transfer_initiate?u_name=rocky");
     // mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

       mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

           @Override
           public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
               handler.proceed();
           }
       });


     }



    }
```

Error Log:

```
    06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): Process: qcash.bd.qcashwallet, PID: 3088
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {qcash.bd.qcashwallet/qcash.bd.qcashwallet.WebViewPtoP}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at qcash.bd.qcashwallet.SelectService$2.onClick(SelectService.java:40)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
06-17 10:11:41.422: E/AndroidRuntime(3088):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is the error log , u get ?

Comment: I have attach the error log. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the Activity in your Android Manifest File. Also, if you have not given Interner permissions, add these lines.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I have already done both of this. 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

`<activity
            android:name="qcash.bd.qcashwallet.SelectService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>`

and

`<activity
            android:name="qcash.bd.qcashwallet.WebviewPtoP"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>`

Comment: One mad thing I would suggest is Invalidate Caches and Restart your Android Studio, Or Restart your Eclipse. This may sometimes solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please read logcat carefully **ActivityNotFoundException:  have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Declare that activity into your manifest file

Comment: if you  are still getting the issue of app crash check logcat and post it here

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the activity from the manifest and then add it again. This time I did not not write the XML directly. Instead, I go to `Application > Application nodes > add`, choose the Activity, and then browse for the file source.

This worked for me.
Thank you everyone for responding.